# how do I make a datatable with ajax response in the form of html if I use codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables, codeigniter-3

I tried to make dropdown search.. how do I make a datatable with ajax response in the form of html if I use codeigniter?

I have tried the console to display the html in response ajax and it works but the response data cannot run on the datatable..

this is my ajax and php code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#example').DataTable();
  $("#periode1").on('change', function(){
      var value = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
        url: '<?= base_url('Kriteria/getPost') ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'request='+value,
        success:function(data)
        {
          console.log(data);
          $("#tampil_kriteria").html(data);
          $('#example').DataTable();
        }
      });

  });
});
```

.

```
public function getPost()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Manajemen Data';
    $data['title2'] = 'Daftar Kriteria';
    $data['user'] = $this->Kriteria_model->getUserById();
    $data['periode'] = $this->Kriteria_model->getAllPeriode();

   $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
   $this->load->view('templates/menu', $data);
   $id = $this->input->post('request');
   if($id){
     $data['kriteria2'] = $this->Kriteria_model->getAllKriteria($id);
     $this->load->view('kriteria/tampil_kriteria', $data); 
   } else {
     $id = $this->Kriteria_model->getId();
     $data['kriteria'] = $this->Kriteria_model->getAllKriteria($id);
     $this->load->view('kriteria/index', $data);
   }
   $this->load->view('templates/footer');            
}
```

Comment: Is the `#tampil_kriteria` inside the DataTable? After DataTables has been initialized, the data inside can't be manipulated with just referencing the element and changing it's contents because DataTables has created it's own data structure at that point.

Comment: provide your html code

Comment: You can do it by server side processing of Data Table [documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side)

Comment: because when im using native php that's ajax work good but when im using codeigniter its not work

Comment: So, you have problem with codeIgniter code. You must have an ajax response from codeIngniter script with all the values and you pass them to datatable as I answered before.

Comment: I'd love to see your working "native PHP" version. In your codeigniter version what is the response that Datatables cannot work with? Does your page have jquery loaded etc (it's a long list). Does your URL in your AJAX get properly set?

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution could be: 
encode the result of your php script in JSON format as:

```
{
   "data": [
    {
      "title": "Manajemen Data",
      "title2": "Satou",
      "user": "Accountant",
      "periode": "Tokyo",
     ......
    },
    {
     "title" : "myTitle2",
     ..........
    }
  ]
}
```

Change your Jquery function as:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "myPhpScript.php",
            "type": "POST"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "title" },
            { "data": "title2" },
            { "data": "user" },
            { "data": "periode" },
           ..........
        ]
    } );
```

where `title, title2, user, periode, ...` are the name of the columns in HTML code

Comment: the ajax code must first create a field, what if the field that I created is dynamic?

Comment: What do you mean dynamic? You mean that you don't know the columns before you retrieve data? If so, you can try to add column in HTML through Jquery programmatically and then you push the values inside datatable instance